# Temporary extending existing object in Java - is this a good idea?

Tags: java, oop

I'm implementing an algorithm during which we must temporary order existing objects (we will compare them according to this order during execution of the algorithm). I'm thinking of the best way of doing that, while being consistent with OOP paradigm.

So let's think about the following example. We have objects of class Car, and now we want to use the algorithm on such objects. So I thought of making a subclass OrderedCar, which will have a unique int in its fields. This class would have a function - `ArrayList<OrderedCar> defineOrder(ArrayList<Car> order)`, which would output OrderedCar list with numbers corresponding to the indices of a given car in order table. We would then be able to compare OrderedCars using  numbers with which they were initialized. We could then execute the algorithm on OrderedCars and convert them to Cars after the algorithm terminates.

During the algorithm I need all of the methods from Car class, that's why I thought of making OrderedCar a subclass. Is this a good idea though? Also, how to create a constructor in Java, which will "copy" the Car and assign a number to it (I'm thinking of something like `public OrderedCar(Car c, int order)`, but what to do with the car c in order to "copy" it? I don't want to copy all of the fields individually, is there some kind of shortcut in Java?)

Comment: Just create a comparator, or better yet, use Java 8 closures to handle this. No need to create a new class just to sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could favor **composition over inheritance** and just create a class that contains a Car and its order:

```
public class OrderedCar{
   private int order;
   private Car car;

   public OrderedCar(int order, Car car){
      this.order = order;
      this.car = car;
   }

   public int getOrder(){
      return order;
   }

   public Car getCar(){
      return car;
   }
}
```

Then you can sort this class by its order, and whenever you needed to operate on its car, you would just call the getCar() function.

Comment: And as this functionality does not depend at all on whether the elements are cars, make it an `OrderedObject<T>` and create `OrderedObject<Car>` when needed. I'd also implement `Compatable<OrderedObject<T>>` so that you can easily compare or sort your ordered objects.

Comment: @mihi I don't disagree with you, but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Favoring composition over inheritence is a huge win; bigger then it at first appears.  More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: If you want the convenience of being able to call all the methods of Car on an OrderedCar, you could implement delegation on all the getter and setter methods  eg:  Color getColor() { return car.getColor();} etc.  If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can autogenerate this kind of code.  If you don't want to supply the order number with the constructor you could have a static variable that increments on each construction and assign that value to order.

Comment: @SteveCohen Yes, I know. I'm keeping it as simple as possible. But your second suggestion assumes that the order matches the instantiation order, which is probably not the case.

Comment: Well, what IS the order, actually, then?  Is it derivable from other attributes of the car?

Comment: No - the order is fully arbitrary, we only need to have it for the algorithm, but it is not dependant on any properties of the Car.

Answer (score 1):

If it is enough for you to compute the order basing on public methods of your Car class I think the simplest solution would be to just implement a comparator.

Here is a small example. I'm using the age property to do the sorting.

```java
public class Car {
    protected int age;
    protected String manufacturer;

    Car(int age, String manufacturer) {
        this.age = age;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.manufacturer + " age: " + this.age;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

    public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {
        // do some complicated comparison using
        // Car public methods, we simple use to 
        // age property here
        return c1.getAge() - c2.getAge();
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CarComparingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car ferrari = new Car(1, "Ferrari");
        Car maserati = new Car(4, "Maserati");
        Car subaru = new Car(3, "Subaru");

        ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        cars.add(ferrari);
        cars.add(maserati);
        cars.add(subaru);

        cars.sort(new CarComparator());

        for(Car c: cars) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```